# Prove that $0\le\int_0^1\log(u){\rm d}x+\frac1{2\pi^2}\int_0^1\frac1{u^2}\left(\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}\right)^2{\rm d}x$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I want to prove a special case of a functional inequality stated in a book. To be specific, let $u(x)$ being a positive, differentiable function on $[0,1]$ with unit mass (i.e., $\int_0^1 u(x){\rm d}x = 1$), then we want to show that
$$0 \leq \int_0^1 \log(u){\rm d}x + \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u^2}\left(\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}x}\right)^2{\rm d}x.$$
In a book, the author resorts to the construction of certain solutions of one-dimensional heat equation and used the eigen-expansion (hence the arguments are very lengthy and involved). Since I am only interested in this special inequality stated above, may I know whether there exists a simpler and more elegant proof ?

Comment: In any case, can you attach a reference to the inequality, and where it is proved?

Comment: The inequality stated here has a generalization that is proved in the last chapter of the book "Entropy and Partial Differential Equations" written by W.A. Day (1993)

Comment: Thanks. To be fair, I'd have seen the term $(\frac{du}{dx})^2$ and always thought some connection to PDE would exist. As it turns out, that kind of stuff also happens to be related to the Poincare and Sobolev inequalities  in PDE and graph theory. Maybe I will try an elementary proof of this, but I think those two inequalities will rear their head.

Comment: Yes, actually if you multiply each of the integrand appearing in the right hand side of the inequality by $u$, the new inequality you will get is the famous "log Sobolev inequality" (loosely speaking, (relative) Fisher information dominates (relative) entropy)

Comment: Ah, the log-Sobolev inequality!  Oh yes, I've seen this and should have recognized it. In some cases that inequality is equivalent (under a different constant) to the two I mentioned earlier. Anyway, I will read your reference and get back, I will basically try to create a version of the proof that is standalone with the help of what I know about the LS inequality. I hope it works! +1 to your question, thanks for the interaction.

Comment: You are welcome! As I mentioned in the statement of the question, the author of that reference book used the construction of certain solutions of one-dimensional heat equation and employed the eigen-expansion (so the arguments are very lengthy and involved), but that argument is used for the generalization of this inequality.

Comment: Oh, the usual proof of the Poincare inequality also goes precisely via that route. You see, there's this whole link between PDE and probability that roughly goes as follows : you have a stochastic process (continuous time), which will have an associated generator which is an operator on functions, mostly a differential operator. Then the solutions of the differential equation form an ONB, around which one can prove concentration bounds for the stochastic process, basically using the fact that the first eigenvalue is kind of "most dominant"! So it comes full circle.

Comment: The generator of the Brownian motion is linked to the heat equation in this way. In fact , usually random walks on graphs have traversal probabilities referred to as "heat kernels" because the heat equation and its eigenexpansions usually get involved. That's a long story, though, and that's not the only connection between the two.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The fact that log Sobolev inequalities has at least "18" different proofs (based on optimal transport, isoperimetric inequality, and etc) really tells me that you will have different route towards the advertised conclusion, so I specifically want to "avoid" the usual proof using eigen-expansions.

Comment: Sure, will keep that in mind when I try writing my answer. It won't come today or tomorrow, will try to fit it in the weekend agenda!

Comment: No worries! I am glad that you can possibly help me on this problem

Comment: Are Fourier expansions OK?

Comment: Hi professor Peres, thank you for your reply! using Fourier implicitly means that we are using "eigen-expansion", this is the route that I want to avoid somehow... Personally I see no beauty of this approach (I have to admit that avoiding this approach is only based on my biased taste).

Comment: Look at the proof of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions   Isn't it beautiful? Now try proving it without Fourier series. This is of the same nature to the inequality you discuss,  though simpler

Comment: Thank you professor Peres! Expansion into trig-series is of course an option, but since here the logarithm is involved, I do not think the same trig-series expansion would work in this case...

Comment: I was unable to write an answer, but really enjoyed working on your problem. I hope to visit more of your questions on the site and interact further. Thank you for the references, I really enjoyed perusing them.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks! No worries! I am glad to discuss with you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations. Define the functional $$F(x,u,u')=\int_0^1\log u+\frac{u'^2}{2\pi^2u^2}\,dx$$ where $u$ satisfies the integral constraint $1=\int_0^1u(x)\,dx$ (so $u$ is a p.d.f.). We will assume that $F$ is finite over its stationary path. Consequently, define the functional to be minimised $$G(x,u,u')=\int_0^1\log u+\frac{u'^2}{2\pi^2u^2}+\lambda u\,dx$$ where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. The Euler-Lagrange equation $G_{u'}'=G_u$ yields $$\frac d{dx}\frac{u'}{\pi^2u^2}=\lambda+\frac1u\implies uu''-2u'^2-\pi^2u^2(\lambda u+1)=0.$$ Let $v=u'^2$. This gives $v^*=2u'(u')^*=2u''$ where $v^*=dv/du$ so the differential equation becomes a first-order ODE $$v^*-\frac4uv=2\pi^2u(\lambda u+1).$$ It is easy to derive the solution $v=\pi^2(Cu^4-2\lambda u^3-u^2)$ for some constant $C$ which leads to $$u'=\pm\pi u\sqrt{Cu^2-2\lambda u-1}.$$ Separation of variables yields the solution $$\arctan\frac{\lambda u+1}{\sqrt{Cu^2-2\lambda u-1}}=\pi x+D$$ for some constant $D$ and after simplification, $$((\lambda^2+C)\cos^2(\pi x+D)-C)u^2+2\lambda u+1=0.$$ Solving the quadratic gives the stationary path $$u_s(x)=\frac{-\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2+C}\sin(\pi x+D)}{(\lambda^2+C)\cos^2(\pi x+D)-C}=-\frac1{\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2+C}\sin(\pi x+D)}$$ where the negative root is chosen to satisfy $u(x)>0$ on $[0,1]$ and $|F|<\infty$. Substituting this into the integral constraint gives $$1=\frac2{\pi\sqrt C}\left[\operatorname{arctanh}\frac{\sqrt{\lambda^2+C}+\lambda\tan(\pi x+D)/2}{\sqrt C}\right]_0^1$$ so that $$\sqrt{\lambda^2+C}=-\frac{\sqrt C}{\cos D\tanh(\pi\sqrt C/2)}.$$ Hence \begin{align}\min F(x,u,u')&=\int_0^1\log u_s+\frac12(Cu_s^2-2\lambda u_s-1)\,dx\\&=-\lambda-\frac12+\int_0^1\log u_s+\frac C2u_s^2\,dx\\&=-\frac{\lambda+1}{2}+\frac{\lambda\sqrt{\lambda^{2}+C}\cos D}{\pi\left(\left(\lambda^{2}+C\right)\cos^2D-C\right)}+\int_0^1\log u_s\,dx\\&=\frac{\Lambda-1}2+\frac{\Lambda\sinh\pi\sqrt C}{2\pi\sqrt C}-\int_0^1\log\left(\Lambda+\frac{\sqrt C\sin(\pi x+D)}{\cos D\tanh(\pi\sqrt C/2)}\right)\,dx\end{align} where $C,\Lambda:=-\lambda>0$.

Comment: Thanks! But at the end we want to show that $\min F(x,u,u') \geq 0$ right? Does the last identity shows this point?

Comment: @FeiCao Unfortunately not, as I don't see a way to evaluate the log-sine integral. As this shows, standard use of calculus of variations may not always be able to derive the optimum of a functional. It might be an interesting discussion in itself to show the inequality $$\int_0^1\log\left(\Lambda+\frac{\sqrt C\sin(\pi x+D)}{\cos D\tanh(\pi\sqrt C/2)}\right)\,dx\le\frac{\Lambda-1}2+\frac{\Lambda\sinh\pi\sqrt C}{2\pi\sqrt C}$$ directly.

Comment: Thanks! I agree the last inequality deserves an separate and detailed discussions! Since no one else answered it, I am going to accept your answer

Comment: @FeiCao I have posted the inequality question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058979/prove-that-int-01-log-left-lambda-sqrt-lambda2c-sin-pi-xd-right-dx) with your question linked.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

OK, after looking back at the various different proofs of the classical log Sobolev inequality, there is at least one way we can vanquish this. It turns out it is just a special case of the inequality stated (and proved) in section 2.1. of the lecture notes "Entropy Methods and Related Functional Inequalities" written by Daniel Matthes. So here is the hammer: 
Assume that $\phi:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex such that $(\phi'')^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is concave, let $\psi$ be such that $(\psi'(s))^2 = \phi''(s)$. Then we have that
$$ \int_0^1 \phi(u){\rm d}x - \phi\left(\int_0^1 u{\rm d}x\right) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^1 (\psi(u)_x)^2{\rm d}x \quad (*)$$
holding for all smooth, positive functions $u$ on $[0,1]$. Notice that if $\phi(s) = \frac 12 s^2$ and $\psi(s) = s$, $(*)$ becomes the usual Poincare inequality
$$\int_0^1 u^2{\rm d}x - \left(\int_0^1 u{\rm d}x\right)^2 \leq \frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_0^1 (\partial_x u)^2{\rm d}x$$
in Daniel's notes the choice is $\phi(s) = s\log(s)$ with $\psi(s) = 2s^{\frac 12}$, leading to the well-known log Sobolev inequality, here we just need to take $\phi(s) = -\log(s)$ with $\psi(s) = \log(s)$, and the game is over.
Remark: I definitely welcome any other different approaches!

Comment: A hammer and a half, but I like hammers! +1

Comment: Thanks Teresa! I will welcome any other different proofs

Comment: Sure, still taking a look through your reference and some of mine. Not looking promising right now, but I will still have a good go at this one.